# Phalcon INVO Application - Volt directory can't be written

Tags: php, phalcon, volt

Iam a beginner in php development. I started learning phalcon framework and was working on the examples provided on the site. Everything was working good then when i started learning the tutorial 2 that is INVO Application, downloaded the complete project and placed in the public html folder and when i executed the APP from localhost its saying Volt directory can't be written. I didnt even change anything in the file, still i believed atleast the homepage will show up but nothing showed up.

what to do? pls help.
iam using ubuntu.

```
$di->set('view', function() use ($config) {

$view = new View(); $view->setViewsDir(APP_PATH . $config->application->viewsDir); $view->registerEngines(array( ".volt" => 'Phalcon\Mvc\View\Engine\Volt' ));
return $view; });

$di->set('volt', function($view, $di) { $volt = new VoltEngine($view, $di);
$volt->setOptions(array( "compiledPath" => "invo/cache/volt/" ));

$compiler = $volt->getCompiler(); $compiler->addFunction('is_a', 'is_a'); return $volt;
}, true);
```

Comment: I don't know the framework, but have you ensured that you have set the proper read/write access? - In ubuntu that is.

Comment: yes read/write  access is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your compiledPath needs to be adjusted. Check the example from the repo:
https://github.com/phalcon/invo/blob/master/app/config/services.php#L72

```
$volt->setOptions(array(
    "compiledPath" => APP_PATH . "cache/volt/"
));
```

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is directory permissions. Can you try chmod -R 777 cache/volt ?

Comment: @MidhunKrishna this way we cannot help you. 'Changed, not working' doet not give us the information we need to help you change your code to make it work in your environment, on your local computer. `"compiledPath" => APP_PATH . "cache/volt/"` is most likely the correct solution for you. When it is not working for you, just echo the APP_PATH and see if that directory exists. Can you tell the error message again when you use `"compiledPath" => APP_PATH . "cache/volt/"`

Answer (score 0):

I was using phalcon tool to create a project when I encountered this error. So I used a chmod command recursively to change directory permissions of my project.

And finally the issue was resolved.

This way of doing things is not recommended for production environment. You can use it during development.